# If $w^\top w=1$ then why does the gradient of $w^\top w-1$ yield different solution if we first use the orthogonality constraint?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $\mathbf w$ satisifies $\mathbf w^\top \mathbf w=1$ then why does minimizing the loss function $$
\mathcal L(\mathbf w)=\mathbf w^\top\mathbf \Sigma \mathbf w-\lambda(\mathbf w^\top\mathbf w-1)
$$ start with taking $\nabla_\mathbf w\mathcal L$ so that it gives the solution as solving an eigenvalue problem:$$
\mathbf \Sigma \mathbf w=\lambda\mathbf w
$$

---

If we use the orthogonality condition for the right side of the first equation then $\mathbf w^\top \mathbf w-1$ would vanish and the solution would become$$
\mathbf \Sigma \mathbf w=0
$$ or the nullspace of $\mathbf \Sigma$

Comment: $w^Tw - 1$ vanishing does not imply that the gradient vanishes also.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. if I use the constraint before taking the gradient then the gradient would be zero, although that is not the case for the other way around

Comment: No... take as simple example $f(x) = x$. Obviously $f(0) = 0$, but is $f'(0) = 0$? Also, you can't take the constraint, since then the gradient is not the same.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. ohh! It makes sense now! Thank you

Comment: You're welcome! :)